# updating photoURL of a user by accessing from firebase storage

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

I am using this javascript code to upload an image to firebase storage then I want to update this image url to user's photoURL (firebase auth)

```
const fileButton = document.querySelector('#fileButton');
var imageURL;

fileButton.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    //get file 
    var file = e.target.files[0];
    //create a storage reference
    var storageRef = storage.ref('profilePictures/' + userUID + '.jpg');
    //upload file
    var task = storageRef.put(file);
    //update progress bar
    task.on('state_changed',
        function progress(snapshot){

        },
        function error(err) {

        },
        function complete(){
            storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
                console.log(url);
                imageURL = url;
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                // Handle any errors
                console.log(error);
            });
            // window.location.replace('/profile');
            var user = auth.currentUser;
            user.updateProfile({
                photoURL: imageURL
            })
            .then(function() {
                // Update successful.
                console.log(user);
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                // An error happened.
                console.log(error);
            });
        }
    );
});
```

image upload on storage is **successfull**
but
photoURL in user data is **NOT SUCCESSFULL**

```
uid: "t2TbJS6ut7NZH4UU8HeAVarGPOw2"
displayName: "Sachin Kumar"
photoURL: null
email: "s@gmail.com"
emailVerified: false
```

what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait for `storageRef.getDownloadURL()` to finish before passing it to `user.updateProfile` like:

```
function complete() {
  storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
      console.log(url);
      imageURL = url;

      // Now you have valid `imageURL` from async call
      var user = auth.currentUser;
      user.updateProfile({ photoURL: imageURL })
        .then(function() { console.log(user) })
        .catch(function(error) { console.log(error) });

    })
    .catch(function(error) { console.log(error) });    
}
```